# How to display String message attribute from a list of its ChatMessage class?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, xhtml, jsf-2.2

I am trying to learn Java and Jsf and have been working on a Chat feature project. I am stuck with trying to display the messages after hitting the send button. The error that comes up in Eclipse is a null pointer exception with my action controller addMessage method from the send button. could you please tell me what's wrong with my code? I've been working on this for 3 days now and have tried applying different solutions from the net but can't seem to fix it. I badly need this asap so I'm posting this here for help. Here are my codes:

XHTML Page:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Chat Room</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

    <!-- Pao edited -->
                        <div class="title" align="center">Welcome to ACT Chat Room</div>

                        <!-- collective chat messages -->
                        <div id="chatMessageList">
                        <table align="center">

                            <tr>
                            <td valign="top">
                            <h:outputText value="#{chatPage.chatMessageList}" />
                            </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                        </div>

                    <!-- chat message -->
                    <div id="chatMessage">
                    <h:form>
                        <table align="center">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Enter Message:</td>
                                <td><h:inputTextarea value="#{chatPage.message}" rows="3" cols="75"/></td>
                                <td><h:commandButton value="Send" action="#{chatPage.addMessage()}" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                         </h:form>
                    </div>

    <!-- End editing here -->

    </h:body>
    </html>
```

ChatPage Class:

```
    @ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped
    public class ChatPage {
        private String username;
        private String message;
        private String creationTime;
        private String id;
        private List<ChatMessage> chatMessageList;
        private ChatMessage chatMessage;

        public ChatPage(){
        }

        (getters and setters)
```

/*method to put chatPage.message in chatMessage.message and add it to chatMessageList*/

```
        public void addMessage(){
        ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
        chatMessage.setMessage(message);
        this.chatMessageList.add(chatMessage);
        }
    }
```

ChatMessage Class:

```
    public class ChatMessage {
        private int id;
        private String message;
        private String creationTime;

        (getters and setters)
    }
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        actportal.view.chat.ChatPage.addMessage(ChatPage.java:65)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
        org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
```

Will appreciate any help with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to have assigned anything to the `chatMessageList` variable, so when trying to add a `ChatMessage` to it a `NullPointerException` occurs. To fix this, add the following line to your `ChatPage` constructor:

```
chatMessageList = new ArrayList<ChatMessage>();
```

You will need to import `java.util.ArrayList`.